# Getting the period from irregularly-spaced time series using OCTAVE

Tags: time-series, signals, octave

I have a two column array of data. First column is time (date in decimal years) and second column is the signal strength. The plot is a triangle wave or should be ideally because the sampling is irregularly timed. I've tried numerous methods to get the period of the wave, including fitting a sine wave to the data via lsqcurvefit, but it doesn't always return the right period.
Using OCTAVE how do I get the period (my main aim) of this/any irregularly-spaced time series?[See plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTZPm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found answer to my own question. The lomb custom function ([here](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22215-lomb-normalized-periodogram)) is one of several at matlab central, but this one works without problems in OCTAVE.

```
[P,f,alpha] = lomb(M,date);
[maxpower,maxpowerindex] = max(P);
rightfreq = f(maxpowerindex);
Period = 1/rightfreq
```

Comment: However, I also discovered recently that under the terms of use, you can't use file-exchange stuff in Octave, so I've stopped using lomb until I buy MATLAB.